# filebeat-index-template.json for ElasticSearch 6.2.4

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I am running ElasticSearch 6.2.4. I tried to create Filebeat index template, but got the following error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "No handler for type [string] declared on field [message]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: No handler for type [string] declared on field [message]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "No handler for type [string] declared on field [message]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

**filebeat-index.template.json**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": true,
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        }
      },
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "template1": {
            "mapping": {
              "doc_values": true,
              "ignore_above": 1024,
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "type": "{dynamic_type}"
            },
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "analyzed"
        },
        "offset": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": "true"
        },
        "geoip"  : {
          "type" : "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
  },
  "template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

I wonder if there is official **filebeat-index-template.json** that work for ElasticSearch 6.2.4

### Other thing that I have tried

- Try `filebeat -c "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml" export template > filebeat.template.json`, but the filebeat will keep running forever without creating anything.
- I've tried to change `"type": "string"` to `"type": "text",`, but got another error where `_all` is deprecated.
- I've also tried to remove `_all`, but ElasticSearch keep have parsing error when Logstash send data to ElasticSearch.

### Filebeat Version [Old]

I also try to find out the version of my Filebeat. I tried

```
> filebeat -v
Loading config file error: Failed to read /root/filebeat.yml: open /root/filebeat.yml: no such file or directory. Exiting.

> filebeat -v -c "/etc/filebeat/filebeat.yml"
(it struck forever)
```

I am following this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04, but instead of using ElasticSearch 2.0 and Kibana 4.5, I am installing ElasticSearch 6.2.4, Kibana 6.2.4, and Logstash 6.2.4 and Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

### Upgrading to Filebeat 6.2.4

Now I am upgrading Filebeat to 6.2.4. Now I get this error

```
Exiting: Could not start registrar: Error loading state: Error decoding states: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []file.State
```

I removed this error by `rm /var/lib/filebeat/registry`. Now I can do `filebeat export template > template.json` and it work fine now. I will close the question soon.

Comment: Which version of filebeat are you running?

Comment: @Val, I have added the answer to your question in the updated post.

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this elastic 6.0 modified json for **filebeat-index.template.json**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "template1": {
            "mapping": {
              "doc_values": true,
              "ignore_above": 1024,
              "index": "false",
              "type": "{dynamic_type}"
            },
            "match": "*"
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {
        "@timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "message": {
          "type": "text",
          "index": "true"
        },
        "offset": {
          "type": "long",
          "doc_values": "true"
        },
        "geoip": {
          "type": "object",
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties": {
            "location": {
              "type": "geo_point"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
  },
  "template": "filebeat-*"
}
```

Basically I changed the message type from ***string*** to ***text***. Also from elastic 6.0 onwards the index field uses ***true*** or ***false***, instead of ***analyzed***.

After running this command (as suggested in the [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04) you are referring to above):

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/filebeat?pretty' -d@filebeat-index-template.json -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I managed to get the correct confirmation from elastic:

```
{ 
  "acknowledged" : true
}
```

I haven't tested it yet, but please let me know if it works for you.

You will probably notice that the **_all** template is also removed from the original json. Why? Apparently it was [depreciated in elastic 6.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-all-field.html) and there are ways to use **copy_to** instead as suggested in [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) but I haven't figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `--es.version 6.2.4` when you generate the template to have it output the appropriate mappings for your version of elasticsearch.

Check out the instructions for [Load the template manually (alternate method)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html#load-template-manually-alternate).  They show the following example for windows but it may work in linux too.

```
PS > .\filebeat.exe export template --es.version 6.6.2 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 filebeat.template.json
```